# How to call a function with multiple values in python?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am developing a script that opens about 24,000 files and does some processing. I use the contents of the file, pass the contents of the file to the process_labs function, which returns 3 strings. I am having troubles with calling the function.  Here is my code:

```
def process_labs (record):
    Some code
return lab1, lab2, lab3


files = sc.wholeTextFiles ('file:///data/*/*/*')
records = files.map(lambda x: x[1])
lab1, lab2, lab3 = records.map(x => process_labs(x))
```

I get an error message right on the ">" just before the *process_labs(x)* is called.

> Error message:
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am calling the function properly in python? I cannot understand where is the syntax error.

Comment: The return statement should have the same indentation as `some code`

Comment: This has nothing to do with multiple values. Why do you think that `=>` is valid syntax in Python?

Comment: That's not the syntax of the lambda, in the `records = ...` you have it right but in the next statement is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `=>` operator in Python. Assuming you meant to use it as a lambda, this is the correct syntax:

```
lab1, lab2, lab3 = records.map(lambda x: process_labs(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me.  I got confused how a function should be called using the map.